# How to finish parent activity from child activity

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-2.2-froyo, android

I am new to Android development.

I have created a main Activity (->A), which has 4 buttons. One of the 4 buttons is the EXIT-button.

I start another activity (->B), on click of the EXIT-button. This opens 'B'Activity via an intent from 'A'Activity.

Activity 'B' contains - Do you want to exit? Yes-Button & No-Button.

If I give finish(), onclick of the button - it exits the 'B'Activity. I want to finish 'B' & 'A'.

I have even tried A.finish() -> this doesn't get recognized and results in syntax/semantic error.

I would appreciate help here.

P.S : I am using Android-2.2 version phone, and I do not like to use ActivityManager to resolve this.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try to launch child activity with

```
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_EXIT);
```

In child activity

```
case R.id.quit:
     setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
     finish();
```

In parent activity

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_EXIT) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            this.finish();

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Does that work if the parent activity didn't appear. I mean I have a button that start another activity. on this button click I also wonna finish the current activity and its parent

Comment: This method will work as long the the child activity was started in the parent activity using startActivityForResult, and onActivityResult is defined in parent.

Answer (score 6):

use `startActivityForResult()` in **Activity A** for start activity B and `onActivityResult()` in A just `finish()` Activity A. In Activity B on Button pressed just `finish()` **Activity B**.

Comment: thanks Georgy has explained the same - i have used his code section into mine.

Answer (score 5):

You can finish parent activity from child activity like...

In Parent....

```
 startActivityForResult(new Intent(Parent.this, Child.class), ACTIVITY_CONSTANT);
```

And override the OnActivityForResult(...) method in Parent .

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_CONSTANT)
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```

When you call finish() on child activity, it finishes parent also.