# Restart app properly

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I use this code to restart my app.

```
Intent i=getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

It does restart the app, jumps to first launch activity. But it goes back to the fragment where the intent was executed when I press back.

Then I added this to nullify backstack:

```
fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Then now when I press back button it goes back to the activity holding the fragment from earlier.

Question:

Should I just override `onBackPressed` on the first launch activity or is there a better way?

Screen A - Splash

Screen B - First Launched Screen

Screen C - Main

Here is what happens when I restart (from main) without finish: C -> B -> A -> *back pressed -> C

So I added finish, then here is what happens: C -> B -> *closes, not a crash

But I already found the answer.

Comment: Restart app means? What exactly you want to do ?

Comment: add finish() with your intent, it will finish the current activity

Comment: @Aniruddha to start again, make the app go back to the splash screen. I'm sorry, but with all due respect, what other definitions does restart have?

Comment: @MeenalSharma it closes the whole app.

Comment: Have a look at `finish` and [`finishActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity())

Comment: what should happen when the user presses the back button when your application is restarted? It should exit your application?

Comment: @LeiLeyba Why do you want to restart your app? Seems like an unlogical flow for the user? Do you want to use of for logging out and going back to starting point for example?

Comment: @RvdK I have an option to let the user reset the app completely, as if the app is a fresh install. Anywyay, I already found the answer. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664108/how-to-finish-parent-activity-from-child-activity), here is how I did it,

On the Splash screen, i put `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_EXIT);`
and

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_EXIT) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            this.finish(); }}}
```

and `setResult(RESULT_OK, null);` on the splash before calling finish.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an activity stack that is just `Home Screen`, so that if the user presses `BACK` button they `EXIT` your application they you would add these two flags

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

```
Intent i = new Intent (this, Home.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

This will finish all the activities in stack between the current activity and the one you are starting.

Hope this will give you some idea. Happy coding.

**I'm assuming that you want to exit your application after restart**